# Most efficient way to achieve the following 2D heat wave background effect?

Tags: unity, 2d, shaders

In Unity, what would be the most efficient way to achieve the following heat wave background effect

Super Metroid - SNES (skip to 34m 5s for those on mobile)

http://youtu.be/yB317FOcU0Y?t=34m5s

Obviously one way of doing this is by animating the sprite directly, which actually might be the most efficient way in terms of GPU, but is definitely more labor intensive. Could a shader be created to do this?

Comment: Most efficient in what way? You've mentioned both GPU and labor.

Comment: In terms of labor and not having to animate any sprites in order to achieve this. I imagine a shader would be the only other route?

Comment: Depends on your skill at writing shaders, or your skill at finding a shader to suit your needs. I think that's the most common route for such things these days.